# Which asset URLs are acceptable in a "vanilla" MU install?

Tags: multisite, uploads, urls

Wordpress appears to let content be addressed by many URIs in an MU install. For example:

```
 example.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/5/files/picture.jpg
 example.com/bob/files/picture.jpg
 example.com/bob/wp-content/blogs.dir/5/files/pictures.jpg
```

All appear to route to the same place. Are there more aliases? Which one is canonical? Are any of these accidental? Are there relevant filters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Short Answer

**example.com/bob/files/picture.jpg is the preferred, canonical URL for images in a WordPress Multisite installation**. The two URLs with `blogs.dir` in the URL are essentially identical, and both leverage the filesystem structure. The path with 'bob' exists because you did a sub-directory install, not a subdomain install. Other paths would exist based on your other sites, e.g. example.com/fred/wp-content/blogs.dir/5/files/pictures.jpg. Otherwise, no other paths exist.

## Long Answer

There's a lot one can explain about this process, and I'm not 100% certain of the level of detail you're looking for, so I'll cove the basics here.

WordPress Multisite stores files by `blog_id` (the "5" after "/blogs.dir/") to keep things organized and separate different sites' files. This directory structure isn't intended to be public. WordPress uses rewrite rules to route `^files/(.+)` to `wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$1`, and then `wp-includes/ms-files.php` processes and outputs the image and/or some helpful headers. There are a few advantages to this:

- In terms of security, less information is always better. "wp-content/blogs.dir/5" is a little TMI -- it says you're running WordPress Multisite and that the `blog_id` is 5.
- The URL structure is identical to that of a single-site installation. If you were to ever move a site from a Multisite installation to its own, you wouldn't have to update those references in the database or 301 the old paths for external references.
- You can move the files directory out of public access or `deny from all` through `.htaccess` so, for instance, people can't access original image sizes if you don't want.
- You can add access control to specific files

There's one main disadvantage, which is that the images/files are passing through PHP (and perhaps even require a few MySQL queries), so it requires more resources. If you have a caching plugin installed, the additional resources should be negligible.

With regards to filters, you can't easily filter anything in the process for one reason: neither [mu-plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins), plugins, or your theme get loaded*. The best you can do is override constants in wp-config.php. Here are the most useful/relevant constants you can override:

```
if ( !defined( 'UPLOADBLOGSDIR' ) )
    define( 'UPLOADBLOGSDIR', 'wp-content/blogs.dir' );

if ( !defined( 'UPLOADS' ) ) {
    // Uploads dir relative to ABSPATH
    define( 'UPLOADS', UPLOADBLOGSDIR . "/{$wpdb->blogid}/files/" );
    if ( 'wp-content/blogs.dir' == UPLOADBLOGSDIR )
        define( 'BLOGUPLOADDIR', WP_CONTENT_DIR . "/blogs.dir/{$wpdb->blogid}/files/" );
}

/**
 * Optional support for X-Sendfile header
 */
if ( !defined( 'WPMU_SENDFILE' ) )
    define( 'WPMU_SENDFILE', false );

/**
 * Optional support for X-Accel-Redirect header
 */
if ( !defined( 'WPMU_ACCEL_REDIRECT' ) )
    define( 'WPMU_ACCEL_REDIRECT', false );
```

*Even though plugins don't get loaded, [drop-ins](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2010/05/01/must-use-and-drop-ins-plugins/) do. Therefore, while you can't use standard plugins, WordPress still lays the foundation to do whatever you need, like (as mentioned above) adding access control to sensitive files. The drop-in `sunrise.php` would be a good place to add such code.

Answer (score 2):

In multisite installs setup with WordPress 3.5 or later, `ms-files.php` is bypassed directly, and `blogs.dir` is not used.

Instead, uploads are stored in `wp-content/blogs/{blog_id}` and referred to as such. This means that there is **only one** way to access files on a subdomain install, and only two on subdirectory install.